# Soma de termos de progressão geométrica

Tags: c, algoritmo

Preciso fazer um programa em que se insira `a1`, `q` , `n` (numero de termos da geométrica) para calcular os termos e depois calcular a soma desses termos.

Consegui fazer o cálculo dos termos, mas não tenho ideia de como calcular a soma.

Segue o que fiz até agora:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    double a1, s;
    int i, q, n;

    scanf ("%lf %d %d", &a1, &q, &n);

    for (i=0; i<=n-1; i++){
     printf("%lf\n", a1);
     a1=a1*q;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seja bem vinda, o calculo da soma dos termos da pg é: Sn = (a1 (q^n - 1) )/(q-1) correto? então já isto: `Sn = ((a1*(pow(q,n) - 1))/(q-1))`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já que precisa dos termos **e** da soma, não é complicado e nada diferente de obter os termos. Eu melhorei algumas coisas:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a1, q, n, soma = 0;
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a1, &q, &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a1);
        a1 *= q;
        soma += a1;
    }
    printf("%d\n", soma);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/GUaKjw). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/SumTermsc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/SumTerms.c).

A solução com fórmula talvez dê uma performance um pouco maior, mas só testando para ter certeza.

Se digitar valores altos a soma pode estourar fácil, aí poderia usar o tipo `long long` para esta variável, mas não melhoraria muito. Poderia usar um `doble` então, mas não faz tanto sentido já que não precisa de parte decimal. Aí o certo seria usar um tipo preparado para isto, mas complicaria muito para um exercício.

Answer (score 1):

Visto que a fórmula do cálculo da soma dos termos de uma progressão aritmética é a seguinte:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo:

**Sn** = Soma dos termos;

**a1** = Primeiro termo;

**q** = Razão;

**n** = número de termos;

Esta formula codificada para a linguagem C ficará:

```
((a1*(pow(q,n) - 1))/(q-1))
```

Entretanto, há um erro no seu código, neste trecho:

```
for (i=0; i<=n-1; i++){
 printf("%lf\n", a1);
 a1=a1*q;
}
```

Você está atribuindo valores ao 1º termo, se finalidade do código fosse somente apresentar os termos estaria correto, entretanto  desta forma sua soma dos termos ficará incorreta, para corrigir tal erro use uma variável auxiliar para mostrar os termos, eu usei a variável `termo`, porém você pode renomeá-la.

```
termo=a1;
for (i=0; i<=n-1; i++){
 printf("O termo da posição %d  = %.0f\n", i, termo);
 termo=termo*q;
    }
```

Seu código com alguns ajustes ficará assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    double a1, sn, termo;
    int i, q, n;
    printf("Insira o 1º Terno: ");
    scanf ( "%lf", &a1);
    printf("Insira  a razão : ");
    scanf ( "%d", &q);
    printf("Insira a quantidade de termos: ");
    scanf ( "%d", &n);

    termo=a1;
    for (i=0; i<=n-1; i++){
     printf("O termo da posição %d  = %.0f\n", i, termo);
     termo=termo*q;
        }
   sn = ((a1*(pow(q,n) - 1))/(q-1));
    printf("Soma dos termos da PG é: %.0f", sn);
  return 0;
}
```

Obs.: Não entendi porque você esta usando double para os termos, entretanto não modifiquei nada referente a isto, somente a saida `%.0f` para mostrar os número sem a parte decimal.

Se houver alguma dúvida referente a formatação aconselho as leituras:

[Sintaxe de especificação de formato: funções printf e wprintf](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=vs-2019)

[C Tutorial – printf, Format Specifiers, Format Conversions and Formatted Output](https://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output)

Comment: Usei double pq meu professor pediu para que fosse possível inserir números decimais

Comment: @esther entendi!

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer há soma é necessário apenas o uso da fórmula de soma dos termos de uma pg

[image: Fórmula]

Para fazer cálculos de exponenciação em C inclua a biblioteca: `<math.h>`
Dica: Use a função `pow()`